# Using IN with a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables, in one the tables there is a column that holds the ID of the other table. This column could hold more than one ID so I am storing it as a list so for instance "1,2,3,4" could be the values. So I try to use the following:

```
SELECT TableAValue
FROM TableA
WHERE TableAID IN 
(SELECT TableAID FROM TableB WHERE TableBID  = 1)
```

This only brings back one value.

Now if I use:

```
SELECT TableAID FROM TableB WHERE TableBID  = 1
```

This brings back four values. Also if I copy those four values and use:

```
SELECT TableAValue
FROM TableA
WHERE TableAID IN 
(1,2,3,4)
```

This will bring back the four values I am after. This seems like something very simple to do, so I guess I'm either doing it completely wrong or I'm missing some small detail. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't store comma delimited lists for 1 to many relationships. You should have a junction table with composite PK `TableAID,TableBID` and an FK relationship to `TableA`

Comment: @MartinSmith According to the question it doesn't seem he is storing data as comma delimited list.

Comment: @Karolis - You haven't read it properly then! Specifically see the second line. Also explains why they get 1 result back from the implict cast. As far as I remember everything from the first non numeric character (comma) is ignored.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think that you read only the first paragraph :)

Comment: @Karolis - Well the first paragraph states that what they are doing and nothing else in the question contradicts that so what's your point?

Comment: @Martin Hmmm... You think that second strong returns one value with the string "1,2,3,4"?

Comment: @Karolis - Yes. Which will be cast to `1` IIRC. The OP is presumably assuming that when plugged into an `IN` clause it will just work as though it was a literal comma delimited list.

Comment: @Karolis : This quote directly states that the 4 values are a comma separated list held in a single field of a single row... `This column could hold more than one ID so I am storing it as a list so for instance "1,2,3,4" could be the values`

Comment: @Martin Ok, most likely you are right.

Comment: @Dems I understood the sentence. But I decided to make an assumption that list "1,2,3,4" is an example of possible values in a column, because the queries are very good for normalized tables. But according to the result he gets it seems that I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments discussion, your mistake is to hold four values in a single field.  Doing so means that you're holding a string, a single value, not a list of integers.  If you want to hold several values, you need several places to hold them individually.

So, if instead you have four records, each with a different value in TableAID, it will work exactly as you expect.

```
CREATE TABLE TableB (
  TableBID INT,
  TableAID INT
)

INSERT INTO TableB
      SELECT 1, 1
UNION SELECT 1, 2
UNION SELECT 1, 3
UNION SELECT 1, 4
UNION SELECT 2, 3
UNION SELECT 2, 4
UNION SELECT 2, 5
UNION SELECT 2, 6
```